# "be happier than someone" or "be happier as somone"?

Tags: difference

Tell me please if there is any difference in meaning between the following sentences.

> He loves his job, so he is happier **than** you are.
>   He loves his job, so he is happier **as** you are.

Comment: *Happier **than*** means "more happy"  ***As** happy **as**.* means "happy to the same degree".  Your second example is not grammatical.   Also the final "are" is not necessary, e.g. *"He is happier than you"*.   In any case, please add more detail to explain why you think these are the same, or why they are confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some difference between these sentences.
It depends on different implication.

"He loves his job, so he is happier than you are".

It means "you are less happy than he is".

"He loves his job, so he is happier as you are".

It means "you are happier (than someone else) as well".

Comment: That is what "happier as you" means, but it is a pretty unusual expression. If someone actually said "He is happier as you" I would probably interpret it as a mistake and understand that they meant "than you".

Comment: I agree that using "than" here is much more natural. But there is a little possibility of using "as" in some specific context.